# optimal solution for application deployed on multiple server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008

I have face one question which is below **"You application has been deployed on multiple servers and you wish to keep checking the health of each of the servers continuously. what would be an optimal solutions to this problems".**

please suggest the proper solution of this question.

Comment: a monitor program of the servers

Answer (score 0):

Probably the IIS Health Monitoring framework would be a good way to answer if it's a mainly Windows shop, though tbh a separate set of *nix servers running Nagios would probably be a better solution overall.